# How do I rename the extension for a bunch of files?

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename

In a directory, I have a bunch of `*.html` files. I'd like to rename them all to `*.txt`

How can I do that?
I use the Bash shell.

Answer (score 417, accepted):

For an better solution (with only bash functionality, as opposed to external calls), see [one of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224766/bash-rename-files/1225236#1225236).

---

The following would do and does not require the system to have the `rename` program (although you would most often have this on a system):

```
for file in *.html; do
    mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .html).txt"
done
```

*EDIT:* As pointed out in the comments, this does not work for filenames with spaces in them without proper quoting (now added above). When working purely on your own files that you know do not have spaces in the filenames this will work but whenever you write something that may be reused at a later time, do not skip proper quoting.

Comment: An alternative, without basename & with quotes: mv "${file}" "${file/%.html/.txt}" (see man bash, Parameter Expansion for details)

Comment: Only good if the files are all in the current directory, of course, because basename strips off the pathname part.  Just a 'beware'!

Comment: if there are many html files, use bash's internal string functions instead of basename.

Comment: +1 for use of basename; although the question specifies it is for the bash shell, portability is good!

Comment: This solution is bad, not only because it is slow but because it does not work with filenames with spaces in them. You should ALWAYS do proper quotation in bash scripts. mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .html)".txt would be much better. But still, mv "$files" "${files%.html}.txt" is much better.

Comment: I agree with Pozsar. If you are not careful, this can really make for a bad day. Just a warning.

Comment: in windows you just do `ren *.a *.b`

Comment: all my files (which has a space in them) vanished except for the last one file which remains as <empt_name>.txt :(

Comment: At minimum, use POSIX-specified `$()` instead of legacy backtick syntax. Improves readability, and makes syntax much less ambiguous when you have characters that would need to be backslash-escaped to be literal inside the command substitution with the latter.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Thanks! Worked! (Just when thought you couldn't do batch commands in windows...)

Comment: For what it's worth, some of the earlier comments are no longer relevant; the quoting errors in this answer were fixed in 2016 so it should be reasonably safe in its current form.

Answer (score 772):

If using Bash, there's no need for external commands like `sed`, `basename`, `rename`, `expr` etc.

```
for file in *.html
do
  mv "$file" "${file%.html}.txt"
done
```

Comment: And if you don't know the file extension you can use `"${file%.*}.txt"`, but this could be dangerous for files w/o an extension at all.

Comment: Note to anyone having trouble getting this working like I had: notice that there is no `$` inside the curly braces!

Comment: I need a way to permanently favorite/bookmark this answer, I never remember the exact syntax and I end up googling for it

Comment: Is there a way to make this work recursively, i.e. even if the files to rename are not directly located in the current working dir but in its various direct and indirect child directories?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is working? Can you explain the logic of the mv command?

Comment: If you google "linux rename multiple extension" you don't find this answer, you find some unsatisfying answers on unix.stackexchange and end up spending some time figuring out the correct one because you know how `mv file{1,2}` works leading to [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169051/3547).

Googling "linux batch rename" would have led me here directly...

Comment: @danip The percent-sign-within-bracket construct strips characters off the end.  There is also a hash-within-bracket construct that strips characters off the beginning.  Check it: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSUB2

Comment: Another Stack exchange answer (that I can't find!) suggested this, but also using the `--` "operator": mv -- "$file" "${file%.html}.txt"  That operator prevents file names that start with a '-' from being parsed by mv as arguments.

Answer (score 206):

```
rename 's/\.html$/\.txt/' *.html
```

does exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't think you can use a literal regex in bash like you suggest - which shell are you using?

Comment: Here's the man page for the version of rename on Ubuntu: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename

Comment: rename is a command on some systems.  I have a Perl script (originally from the first Camel book) that does the job.  There's also a GNU program of the same name that does roughly the same job.
My Mac doesn't have a system-provided 'rename' command - or it isn't on my PATH (which is moderately comprehensive).

Comment: There is a rename formula in Homebrew.

Comment: I like your answer. But in fact i will just use `rename 's/jpg/png/' *.jpg`, this is easier to remember and type. It may cause error if there is a filename contains jpg, so I will check it first before typing.

Answer (score 152):

This worked for me on OSX from .txt to .txt_bak

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.txt}.txt_bak"' {} \;
```

Comment: Works fine in linux too.

Comment: It's besides the point, but to go from `.txt` to `.txt_bak` you just have to concatenate `_bak` ;)

Comment: This is nice for renaming recursively

Comment: Great! (under Ubuntu 16.04) My practical use case, renaming all `.scss` to `.sass` (after in-place conversion…): `find . -name '*.scss' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.scss}.sass"' {} \;`

Comment: this worked with +6000 files, rename reported "argument list was too long"

Comment: I used it in windows in GIT hooks (which means the shell (Linux))- it works nice. I wanted to remove the .tmp extension, so that I used it a little bit modified:
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.tmp}"' {} \;
(in case somebody wants to rename the extension with nothing (remove the .tmp extension of the files)
Thnx @Steven

Answer (score 103):

You want to use [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) :

```
rename -S <old_extension> <new_extension> <files>

rename -S .html .txt *.html
```

This does exactly what you want - it will change the extension from `.html` to `.txt` for all files matching `*.html`.

*Note: Greg Hewgill correctly points out this is not a bash builtin; and is a separate Linux command. If you just need something on Linux this should work fine; if you need something more cross-platform then take a look at one of the other answers.*

Comment: Although this is a good solution, the `rename` program is not related to `bash` and is also not available on all platforms. I've only seen it on Linux.

Comment: "$rename .html .txt *.html" results in...
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "."

Comment: @Greg: Ah yes you're right - I'd always assumed it was a bash builtin. However I don't think I've ever come across a Linux system which didn't have it; so if you're only need this for Linux rename is probably the simplest method.

Comment: Correct syntax is `rename -S .html .text *.html` where `-S` stands for `--subst-all`

Comment: @GregHewgill rename is available for Mac OS with HomeBrew

Comment: I updated the answer to add the missing -S switch as per @MarekSebera correction.

Comment: There is no -S option for rename 2.28.2 of util-linux. It works without it, though.

Comment: My Ubuntu 16 doesn't include -S for rename.

Comment: Unknown option: S on ubuntu

Comment: On Mac with Homebrew rename version use lowercase s for substitute command: `rename -s .html .txt *.html`

Comment: Just to recap what several of the comments here are implying, but few are saying; there are multiple `rename` tools with different options and different syntax, even if you have exactly the same base Linux (or FreeBSD etc) system as somebody else. What works depends on which `rename` you have, if you have one at all. This is all nonstandard, so YMMV.

Answer (score 36):

On a Mac...

1. Install [rename](http://digitalcardboard.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/rename) if you haven't: `brew install rename`
2. `rename -S .html .txt *.html`

Answer (score 16):

For Ubuntu Users :

```
rename 's/\.html$/\.txt/' *.html
```

Comment: This isn't recursive, but it worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 16):

This is the slickest solution I've found that works on OSX and Linux, and it works nicely with git too!

`find . -name "*.js" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.js}".tsx' - '{}' \;`

and with git:

`find . -name "*.js" -exec bash -c 'git mv "$1" "${1%.js}".tsx' - '{}' \;`

Comment: Not really slick, since it starts a new bash for every single file. Quite slow, actually. Use pipe and xargs, please.

Comment: I suppose that's true. I can't imagine many cases where you're naming so many files that performance would matter. This method can rename hundreds within seconds.

So yeah, I guess maybe it's not great performance, but it's a slick solution if you don't...

Comment: There is another limitation here compared to the xargs solution: You can't easily parallelize it. With `xargs` you can simply add `-P 10` and it will fork you command with up to 10 concurrent processes. Really good for handling large directories. Use of `ls -1` was just an example of how to feed `xargs` - you could use it with find too

Answer (score 10):

This question explicitly mentions Bash, but if you happen to have ZSH available it is pretty simple:

```
zmv '(*).*' '$1.txt'
```

If you get `zsh: command not found: zmv` then simply run:

```
autoload -U zmv
```

And then try again.

Thanks to this [original article](https://coderwall.com/p/yepegw/mass-renaming-files-with-zmv-zsh) for the tip about zmv.

Comment: `zmv '(*).html' '$1.txt'` to use the specific file extensions from the original question.

Answer (score 9):

In Linux or window git bash or window's wsl, try below command to change every file's extension in current directory or sub-directories or even their sub-directories with just one line of code

```
find . -depth -name "*.html" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.html}.txt"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: worked for me in windows 11 git bash (MINGW64).

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of the rename command:

```
rename -n ’s/\.htm$/\.html/’ *.htm
```

The -n means that it's a test run and will not actually change any files. It will show you a list of files that would be renamed if you removed the -n. In the case above, it will convert all files in the current directory from a file extension of .htm to .html.

If the output of the above test run looked ok then you could run the final version:

```
rename -v ’s/\.htm$/\.html/’ *.htm
```

The -v is optional, but it's a good idea to include it because it is the only record you will have of changes that were made by the rename command as shown in the sample output below:

```
$ rename -v 's/\.htm$/\.html/' *.htm
3.htm renamed as 3.html
4.htm renamed as 4.html
5.htm renamed as 5.html
```

The tricky part in the middle is a Perl substitution with regular expressions, highlighted below:

```
rename -v ’s/\.htm$/\.html/’ *.htm
```

Answer (score 7):

One line, no loops:

```
ls -1 | xargs -L 1 -I {} bash -c 'mv $1 "${1%.*}.txt"' _ {}
```

Example:

```
$ ls
60acbc4d-3a75-4090-85ad-b7d027df8145.json  ac8453e2-0d82-4d43-b80e-205edb754700.json
$ ls -1 | xargs -L 1 -I {} bash -c 'mv $1 "${1%.*}.txt"' _ {}
$ ls
60acbc4d-3a75-4090-85ad-b7d027df8145.txt  ac8453e2-0d82-4d43-b80e-205edb754700.txt
```

Comment: +1 for showing a bash-only way which does not depend on matching the existing extension exactly. This works for any input extension, be it 3 chars long or 4 chars long or more

Comment: Improvement: $ ls -1 | xargs -L 1 -I {} bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.*}.swift"' _ {}

Comment: You don't need `ls` or `xargs`; `for f in ./*; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}.swift; done`

Answer (score 5):

The [command `mmv`](https://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html) seems to do this task very efficiently on a huge number of files (tens of thousands in a second). For example, to rename all `.xml` files to `.html` files, use this:

```
mmv ";*.xml" "#1#2.html"
```

the `;` will match the path, the `*` will match the filename, and these are referred to as `#1` and `#2` in the replacement name.

Answers based on `exec` or pipes were either too slow or failed on a very large number of files.

Comment: This is obscure and nonstandard; it might be the same as https://github.com/rrthomas/mmv but the man page you link to reveals nothing about its provenance or availability.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
rename .html .txt *.html
```

usage:

```
rename [find] [replace_with] [criteria]
```

Answer (score 4):

After someone else's website crawl, I ended up with thousands of files missing the .html extension, across a wide tree of subdirectories.

To rename them all in one shot, except the files already having a .html extension (most of them had none at all), this worked for me:

```
cd wwwroot
find . -xtype f \! -iname *.html   -exec mv -iv "{}"  "{}.html"  \;  # batch rename files to append .html suffix IF MISSING
```

In the OP's case I might modify that slightly, to only rename *.txt files, like so:

```
find . -xtype f  -iname *.txt   -exec filename="{}"  mv -iv ${filename%.*}.{txt,html}  \;
```

Broken down (hammertime!):

-iname *.txt
  - Means consider ONLY files already ending in .txt

mv -iv "{}.{txt,html}"
  - When **find** passes a {} as the filename, ${filename%.*} extracts its basename without any extension to form the parameters to **mv**. **bash** takes the {txt,html} to rewrite it as two parameters so the final command runs as: `mv -iv "filename.txt" "filename.html"`

Fix needed though: dealing with spaces in filenames

Answer (score 4):

This is a good way to modify multiple extensions at once:

```
for fname in *.{mp4,avi}
do
   mv -v "$fname" "${fname%.???}.mkv"
done
```

Note: be careful at the extension size to be the same (the ???)

Answer (score 4):

Rename file extensions for all files under current directory and sub directories without any other packages (only use shell script):

1. Create a shell script `rename.sh` under current directory with the following code:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   for file in $(find . -name "*$1"); do
     mv "$file" "${file%$1}$2"
   done
   ```
2. Run it by `./rename.sh .old .new`.

   Eg. `./rename.sh .html .txt`

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as the find solution above: You can't parallelize it as easily. Sure, you can add `&` to your `mv`, but then you could have 100s or 1000s of spawned processes. Using `xargs` you can assure yourself that `-P 20` will allow a max of 20 forked processes.

Comment: `for file in $(find ...)` is inherently broken for file names which contain whitespace or shell metacharacters. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party. You could do it with xargs:

```
ls *.html | xargs -I {} sh -c 'mv $1 `basename $1 .html`.txt' - {}
```

Or if all your files are in some folder

```
ls folder/*.html | xargs -I {} sh -c 'mv $1 folder/`basename $1 .html`.txt' - {}
```

Comment: No. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). This command is ridiculous: it uselessly uses a glob with `ls`, instead of directly using the glob. This will break with filenames containing spaces, quotes and (due to the lack of quotes) glob characters.

Comment: FYI, your linked article contains an updated note that says newer LS 'correctly "shell escapes" files if printed to the terminal.' Your point is still a good rule of thumb though.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to what was suggested before, this is how I did it:

```
find . -name '*OldText*' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0/OldText/NewText}"' {} \;
```

I first validated with

```
find . -name '*OldText*' -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$0" "${0/OldText/NewText}"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use `rename.ul`  it is  present in most of the Linux distro

rename.ul -o -v [oldFileExtension] [newFileExtension] [expression to search for file to be applied with]

```
rename.ul -o -v .oldext .newext *.oldext
```

Options:

-o: don't overwrite preexisting .newext

-v: verbose

-n: dry run

Comment: This surprised me and TIL that this exists in Ubuntu 20.04 out of the box. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer Perl, there is a short Perl script (originally written by Larry Wall, the creator of Perl) that will do exactly what you want here:
[tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt](http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt).

For your example the following should do the trick:

```
rename.pl 's/html/txt/' *.html
```

Comment: This question has already been answered and accepted a long time ago and it doesn't seem that your answer bring anything more than what has already been said.

Comment: +1 since it was a Larry Wall script (modified by Robin Barker). The last available url is this: http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not trivial to do portably. You probably need a bit of expr magic.

```
for file in *.html; do echo mv -- "$file" "$(expr "$file" : '\(.*\)\.html').txt"; done
```

Remove the echo once you're happy it does what you want.

**Edit:** `basename` is probably a little more readable for this particular case, although `expr` is more flexible in general.

Comment: While this may not be the best answer for the question, it was for me! I needed a way to rename only in string a whole path, not just a the file name. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i used to rename `.edge` files to `.blade.php`

```
for file in *.edge; do     mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .edge).blade.php"; done
```

Works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Nice & simple!

```
find . -iname *.html  -exec mv {} "$(basename {} .html).text"  \;
```

Comment: `"$(basename {} .html).text"` gets expanded by the shell to `{}.text` before `find` runs; this is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a function in Bash, add it to `.bashrc` or something and then use it wherever you want.

```sh
change-ext() {
    for file in *.$1; do mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .$1).$2"; done
}
```

Usage:

```sh
change-ext css scss
```

Source of code in function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1224786/6732111

Comment: If you get the error 'Bad substitution', then the 'sh' command probably doesn't point to bash. Replace sh with /bin/bash and it should work.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker there is nothing here which is specific to Bash, or would produce a "bad substitution" error (though `."$1"` should have quotes around it in both places).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, using AWK. Make sure the files are present in the working directory. Else, **cd** to the directory where the html files are located and then execute the below command:

```
for i in $(ls | grep .html); do j=$(echo $i | grep -oh "^\w*." | awk '{print $1"txt"}'); mv $i $j; done
```

Comment: This has multiple problems for robustness and portability; probably run it through https://shellcheck.net/ for full diagnostics. In brief, [don't use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code in my .bashrc

```
alias find-ext='read -p "Path (dot for current): " p_path; read -p "Ext (no punctuation): " p_ext1; find $p_path -type f -name "*."$p_ext1'
alias rename-ext='read -p "Path (dot for current): " p_path; read -p "Ext (no punctuation): " p_ext1; read -p "Change by ext. (no punctuation): " p_ext2; echo -en "\nFound files:\n"; find $p_path -type f -name "*.$p_ext1"; find $p_path -type f -name "*.$p_ext1" -exec sh -c '\''mv "$1" "${1%.'\''$p_ext1'\''}.'\''$p_ext2'\''" '\'' _ {} \;; echo -en "\nChanged Files:\n"; find $p_path -type f -name "*.$p_ext2";'
```

In a folder like "/home/<user>/example-files" having this structure:

- /home/<user>/example-files:

  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.pdf
  - file4.csv

The commands would behave like this:

```
~$ find-text
Path (dot for current): example-files/
Ext (no punctuation): txt

example-files/file1.txt
example-files/file2.txt


~$ rename-text
Path (dot for current): ./example-files
Ext (no punctuation): txt
Change by ext. (no punctuation): mp3

Found files:
./example-files/file1.txt
./example-files/file1.txt

Changed Files:
./example-files/file1.mp3
./example-files/file1.mp3
~$
```

Comment: "Punctured" would mean "having a small undesired hole"; I guess you mean without punctuation?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: Probably prefer functions over aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool designed for renaming files in bulk, e.g. [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer).

To rename all file extensions in the current folder:

```
$ renamer --find ".html" --replace ".txt" --dry-run *
```

Many more usage examples [here](https://github.com/75lb/renamer/wiki/Examples).