# How can be renaming suffix of files done?

Tags: python, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a lot of like abc_model1.pdb.1,...,abc_model1.pdb.100. I want to change these files as  abc_model1_1.pdb , ...,abc_model1_100.pdb. I tried several unsuccessful attempts to modify codes as given in '[How do I rename the extension for a batch of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224766/how-do-i-rename-the-extension-for-a-batch-of-files)'. How can I do using python?

Comment: If you have the `rename` utility (the one from  the `perl` package, _not_ the one from util-linux) installed, then all you need is the simple command: `rename 's/\.pdb\.(\d+)$/_$1.pdb/' *`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

file_dir = '/user/foo/bar/somewhere/'
dest_dir = file_dir # Change this to where you want
                    # the renamed files to go.

for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(file_dir,'*.pdb.*')):
    filename_temp, number = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename_temp)
    shutil.move(file, os.path.join(dest_dir,
                             '{}_{}{}'.format(filename,number,ext)))
```

Comment: Looks like you've only got one argument in your call to `shutil.move` there.

Comment: Yep, thanks for that - lack of coffee in the morning.

Comment: Why `shutil.move` instead of `os.rename`?

Comment: It uses `os.rename` when required: _"If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is used. Otherwise, src is copied (using shutil.copy2()) to dst and then removed."_ [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move).