# Is there a way to undo a batch-rename of file extensions?

Tags: rename, batch-rename

Ok so I kinda dropped the ball. I was trying to understand how things work. I had a few html files on my computer that I was trying to rename as txt files. This was strictly a learning exercise. Following the instructions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224766/how-do-i-rename-the-extension-for-a-batch-of-files) using this code:

```
for file in *.html
do
 mv "$file" "${file%.html}.txt"
done
```

produced this error:

> mv: rename *.html to *.txt: No such file or directory

Long story short I ended up going rogue and renaming the html files, as well as a lot of other non html files as txt files. So now I have files labeled like

- my_movie.mp4.txt
- my_song.mp3.txt
- my_file.txt.txt

This may be a really dumb question but.. Is there a way to check if a file has two extensions and if yes remove the last one? Or any other way to undo this mess?

**EDIT**

Doing this `find . -name "*.*.txt" -exec echo {} \; | cat -b` seems to tell me what was changed and where it is located. The `cat -b` part is not necessary but I like it. This still doesn't fix what I broke though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if terminal can check for extensions "twice", but you can check for `.` in every name an if there's more than one occurence of `.`, then your file has more extensions. Then you can cut the extension off with finding first occurence of `.` in a string when going backwards... or last one if checking characters in string in a normal way.

I have a faster option for you if you can use python. You can strip the extension with:

```
for file in list_of_files:
    os.rename(file,os.path.splitext(file)[0])
```

which can give you from `your file.txt.txt` `your file.txt`

**Example:**

You wrote that your command tells you what has changed, so just take those changed files and dump them into a file(path to file per line). Then you can easily run this:

```
with open('<path to list>') as f:
    list_of_files = f.readlines()
for file in list_of_files:
    os.rename(file.strip('\n'), os.path.splitext(file.strip('\n'))[0])
```

---

If not, then you'd need to get the list from python:

```
import os
results = []
for root, folder, filenames in os.walk(<your path to folder>):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.txt.txt'):
            results.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

With this you got a list of files ending with `.txt.txt` like this `<your folder>\\<path_to_file>`.

Get a path to your directory used in `os.walk()` without folder's name(it's already in list) so it'll be like this:

e.g. `os.walk('/home/me/directory')` -> `path='/home/me/'` and res is item already in a list, which looks like `directory/...`

```
for res in results:
    path = '' # set the path here
    file = os.path.join(path,r)
    os.rename(file, os.path.splitext(file)[0])
```

Depending on what files you want to find change `.txt.txt` in `if filename.endswith('...')` to whatever you like and `os.rename()` will take file's name without extension which in your case means it strips the additional extension you don't want to have.

Comment: This may be correct but I have 0 experience using python. If you could point out the variables in your answer it would help me to understand it better.

Comment: @user556068 I added an example for you so it'd be simple for you to use python.

Comment: Wow yes you certainly did. I don't mean to break the rules but thank you this thorough answer.