# Using sed to split a file by a sequence. bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed, seq

I want to cut a 211,548,559 lines file into 10 smaller files. So, the first file, for example will have 1st to 21154856th line

I would like to write a for loop with a seq that allows me to automatize the process.

I tried to create a function first and then a loop with seq.

```sh
run_sed(){
    sed -n $1p Bar08_depth_chr1.txt > Bar8_d_c1_$1.txt
}
for pos in seq 1 10 211548559
do
    run_sed $pos
done
```

This script didn't work. I believe its because the $1 in `sed -n 1$p` But I don't know how to solve it

Comment: What about `man split`?

Comment: do yeah mean manually split the 10 files? Yeah, I can do that, but I have other files I need to do it in 100 or even more.

Comment: No, he was talking about the command `split`. You can read its manual by running the command `man split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GNU `split`:

```
split -nl/10 --additional-suffix=.txt -d Bar08_depth_chr1.txt Bar8_d_c1_
```

Which will create 10 files named `Bar8_d_c1_00.txt` through `Bar8_d_c1_09.txt` which will likely not need to be renamed.

For `split` under MacOS:

```
split -l $(( (211548559 - 9) / 10 )) Bar08_depth_chr1.txt Bar8_d_c1_
```

Which will create 10 files named `Bar8_d_c1_aa` through `Bar8_d_c1_aj` which can be [renamed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1224766/26428) to the name pattern you need.

The calculation shown causes the number of lines per file to be rounded up in order to avoid a very small 11th file.

Comment: Why not just `split -nl/10`?

Comment: @vintnes: The version of `split` that I was looking at doesn't support that. I'll add that version to my answer. Thanks.