# How to change a bunch of file extensions in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rename, batch-rename

I was trying to change a bunch of files extensions from yml to yaml, and I've found a very good answer here in Stackoverflow. Based on that answer which was:

```bash
for file in *.yml
do
  mv "$file" "${file%.yml}.yaml"
done
```

I've turned it into a command to make my life easier, which I've tried to share there as a comment, but since it required me 50 points to add a comment, I couldn't, then I decided to create this question as a kind of post. How can we convert that answer into a command:

###### Create the file `chgext` to add the script

`vi chgext`

###### Copy and paste the script below into the `chgext` file

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.$1
do
  mv "$file" "${file%.$1}.$2"
done
```

Save and exit pressing: esc + : + x + enter

###### Make `chgext` executable

`chmod +x chgext`

###### Move it to `/usr/local/bin` so it can be called from any directory as any other linux command

`sudo mv chgext /usr/local/bin`

###### Now you are ready to go, call `chgext` passing `old_extension` and `new_extension` as params, like this from the directory where your files are

`chgext yml yaml`

The original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224766/how-do-i-rename-the-extension-for-a-bunch-of-files)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to improve it, like changing your title from being very generic to something that is a short description of your actual problem.